# Road Bike or Hybrid Bike For Paving Stone

Tags: road-bike, hybrid-bike

I haven't got any experience for these bikes. I want to buy a bike but I can't decide because I will use on paving stone. For example [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T-4s9S0idLE/UW-QHlgv_nI/AAAAAAAAAaY/6geZkO80Bpo/s1600/IMG_0025.jpg).

I'd like to buy a hybrid bike however I saw [this](http://www.decathlon.co.uk/fit-3-road-bike-grey-id_8239797.html)
bike in Decathlon and I fell in love with it. This situation confuses me. Which bike type should I buy ? Hybrid or road bike ? Will I have a problem by road bike on paving stone ?

Answer (score 3):

Those paving stones look fine - you could take just about any bike along them.  it's worth considering that there are bike races on [far worse](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/1%C3%A8re_partie_carefour_de_l%27arbre.jpg) pavements - the Paris Roubaix famously.

So you don't need to worry about that.  I would say that the bike you linked to in Decathlon is also a hybrid - it's not a 'road bike' in the traditional sense, which would imply drop handlebars, more like this one:  http://www.decathlon.co.uk/triban-3-road-bike-white-id_8239800.html

(I have no idea what that bike's like - it's just the first one which came up)

As to which one you would buy.. well try them out, see which styles you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can ride the road one for my area. That sounds good.

Comment: That bike looks good. Did you end up getting it?

Answer (score 0):

Like 7thGalaxy stated, a path like that should not prove to be an obstacle for most any bike. I recently started cycling again for commuting reasons and went the cyclocross route by purchasing a [Raleigh Roper](http://www.raleighusa.com/bikes-road-cyclocross-roper). The Roper is running a 700c tire with a very slight knobby on the edge in case I need to leave the hard-pack for any reason. Also, I love the drops as they make riding any sort of distance that much more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I want to buy a road bike then.

Comment: @pasuedxzbl worth noting though that a Cyclocross (CX) bike is not the same as a Road bike. CX bikes are built for rougher terrain and typically have wider tyres. One reason you might want to go the CX route could be enhanced braking - road bikes have quite simple braking mechs - although frankly the road in your photo would be easily navigable by a road bike. In fact it looks positively inviting compared to some of the tarmac I ride on - on a road bike with 23mm tyres

Comment: @PeteH Good call on braking. One of the main reasons I went with the Roper is that I wanted disc brakes. Although, I can't even count the number of times I've seen videos of someone flipping over the front after grabbing too much front brake no matter what type of bike.

Comment: @Owen - yeah I think that's quite a common choice. Although I was quite impressed once when I managed to stop my road bike from 70km/h over just a few hundred metres. (After my taillight fell off!). So even road brakes are effective.